# Set user-agent with selenium-webdriver and phantomjs in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, user-agent

I need to change the User-Agent of my PhantomJS browser that's driving selenium-webdriver.

I've found [methods to change the user agent in C#, Ruby and Java](http://simply-tutorial.com/blog/2014/07/10/selenium-webdriver-set-browsers-user-agent-and-proxy/)

This is what I've tried:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0";

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", useragent)).
    build();
```

The result on the web server still looks like this:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.7 Safari/534.34`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
       .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs()
       .set("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", useragent))
       .build();
```

This is a solution that worked for me.